# Create a Collection with PartitionKey in CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want to create a Collection in Code using the DocumentClient like this

```
await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync (
   UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(databaseId),
   new DocumentCollection { Id = collectionId },
   new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 1000 }
);
```

But how do I add a `PartitionKey`? In the CosmosDB Emulator I just add the name of the property on my class for the collection. Cant work it out. Could be I'm missing something fundamental here. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `DocumentCollection.PartitionKeyDefinition`

```
DocumentCollection collectionDefinition = new DocumentCollection();
collectionDefinition.Id = collectionId;
collectionDefinition.PartitionKey.Paths.Add("/deviceId"); //--> add this

DocumentCollection partitionedCollection = await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
    UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(databaseId),
    collectionDefinition,
    new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 10100 });
```

Comment: Thanks very much. can't upvote this as I dont have enough reputation points.

Comment: Just did (I think). Thans again. Worked perfectly.