# Storage setting on Azure Cosmos DB keeps changing from Unlimited to Fixed when deleting and re-creating database using API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am currently seeding our Cosmos DB using the Azure API via a C# console application. During this process, I delete and recreate the database to ensure that all pre-existing data is removed (this might not be the best option, but I did not see a truncate all option). Originally, the database has the storage setting set to unlimited as seen below.

[image: storage setting on db is set to unlimited]

However, once I delete and recreate the DB, it changes the storage option to fixed as seen below.

[image: storage setting on db is set to fixed after recreate]

I have been googling around for a fix and all I can find is the ability to add a `RequestOptions` to the request that creates the DB. Unfortunately, this only gives me the ability to edit the throughput of the database.

How do I go about changing the storage type when I re-create the database?

**UPDATE:**
Here is how I go about creating the database. The statement is rather trivial which is why I didn't include it in the original post.

```
try 
{
    await this.client.DeleteDatabaseAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(environment.Settings.DatabaseName));
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

await this.client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database { Id = environment.Settings.DatabaseName });
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you've written for recreating the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to specify Partition key for creating storage capacity unlimited

```
var collection = new DocumentCollection
                {
                    Id = collectionName,
                    DefaultTimeToLive = -1
                };
    collection.PartitionKey.Paths.Add(partitionKey);
    var response = await this.cosmosDbClient.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(this.databaseUri, collection, new RequestOptions
                {
                    OfferThroughput = offerThroughput
                });
```

Thanks,
Shraddha Agrawal

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks. I could not find that info for the life of me.

Comment: Agrawal, what format should the partition key be in? I notice you have a variable declared, but I can't see the value of it.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261296/create-a-collection-with-partitionkey-in-cosmosdb